# Weird gray space above page in iOS Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, safari, ios6

If you go to www.projectjuice.com on an iOS device (running 6+) on the Safari browser, you will see there is gray space at the top while any page is loading.

Once the page loads completely, it shifts up again.

Any ideas why of how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's a apple smart banner. Look in you meta tags after `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID>` and remove it or add the correct appStoreId.